# Is there a way to have a macro create multiple statically allocated global arrays that are page aligned?

Tags: c

I know the question is asking for something that is pretty hacky as the proper way to do this would probably be to create a memory allocator as I'm coding for bare metal with no access to the std. However is there a way to create multiple arrays that are static in a loop in a macro?

for example

```
unsigned int page_table_directory[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
unsigned int page_table[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
```

I would like a way to make a macro which makes ~64 of those page table arrays and load the addresses into the page table directory.

The contents of the page table directory would look something like

```
page_table_directory = [0x10c000 ,0x10b000, 0x10a000, ...63 more addresses..., 0x0, 0x0, ... ]
```

With each of those addresses leading to individual page aligned statically allocated arrays.

Further elaboration:

Right now I have a hacky setup where I declare and assign

```
unsigned int page_table_0[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
unsigned int page_table_1[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
unsigned int page_table_2[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
unsigned int page_table_3[1024] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));

# then in main
main() {
page_table_directory[0] = (unsigned int)page_table_0;
page_table_directory[1] = (unsigned int)page_table_1;
page_table_directory[2] = (unsigned int)page_table_2;
page_table_directory[3] = (unsigned int)page_table_3;
}
```

So essentially I want to move that code in the main INTO a macro in addition to making it a loop so I can declare many pages.

Comment: Show the usecase for the proposed macro.

Comment: The addresses can always be computed from the base address.

Comment: Can you tell what **exactly** you want the macros to expand to?

Comment: Are you aware of the undef-free version of X-macros?

Comment: @tadman Can they?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to re-invent something, though I'm not entirely sure what. Can you clarify your constraints and your reasons for not using traditional methods?

Comment: I know about undef but not sure what you mean by undef-free version

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You'd have to set this up specifically as a 2D array. I commented before the "further elaboration" which goes in an unexpected direction.

Comment: I'm essentially being lazy and relying on the auto page alignment with the attributes, I didn't want to try implementing logic with computating the addresses and worrying about page alignment. Context is recreating a basic kernel's main right after boot in.

Comment: Can't you just `malloc` a whole whack of memory and then carve out the aligned chunks you need?

Comment: So yeah, what about a two dimensional array?  `unsigned int page_table_directory[1024];` and `unsigned int page_tables[64][1024];`.  And then a loop at runtime to do `for (i=0; i < 64; i++) page_table_directory[i] = (unsigned int)(page_tables[i]);`.  No macros needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge He wants them 4096-aligned. An array-based solution wouldn't leave the 3KiB gaps occupiable by other globals.

Comment: @PSkocik: They are 4K each (assuming `sizeof(unsigned int)==4`) so they will all be aligned, provided that the whole array is aligned to 4K, and there are no gaps.

Comment: @tadman malloc isn't available so I would have to code up my own version of that

Comment: I had missed that. Agreed, then. A 2-D array is the obvious solution.

Comment: @NateEldredge  [There aren't any gaps](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20): "An array type describes a **contiguously allocated** nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a macro create multiple statically allocated global arrays that are page aligned?

Yes, there is.

> I want to move that code in the main INTO a macro in addition to making it a loop so I can declare many pages.

Preprocessor has macros but it doesn't have loops. Either way or the other, you'll have to enumerate all cases in the preprocessor. Here is a simple example with a generic macro that takes a function and expands up to some limit up to max 5.

```
#define FORTO_0(func, arg)  
#define FORTO_1(func, arg)  func(0, arg)
#define FORTO_2(func, arg)  FORTO_1(func, arg) func(1, arg)
#define FORTO_3(func, arg)  FORTO_2(func, arg) func(2, arg)
#define FORTO_4(func, arg)  FORTO_3(func, arg) func(3, arg)
#define FORTO_5(func, arg)  FORTO_4(func, arg) func(4, arg)
// etc. add... more....
#define FORTO_X(num, func, arg)  FORTO_##num(func, arg)

// num - a number, like 5, will iterate from 0...(N-1)
// func - a function to apply on numbers
// arg - passed as the second argument to func
#define FORTO(num, func, arg)    FORTO_X(num, func, arg)


#define TO  5

#define DEF_PAGE_TABLE(N, _)  \
        unsigned int page_table_##N[1024] __attribute__((__aligned__(4096)));
FORTO(TO, DEF_PAGE_TABLE, _)

int main() {
    unsigned int *page_table_directory[TO];

#define POINT_PAGE_TABLE_DIRECTORY(N, _)   \
        page_table_directory[N] = page_table_##N;
    FORTO(TO, POINT_PAGE_TABLE_DIRECTORY, _);
}
```